# finding out if a checkedbox is selected

Tags: javascript, html, editablegrid

I'm using EditableGrid for the sorting of an HTML-table. This table is generated via a MVC-Controller (as a string) and has an id(#htmlgrid). The table is displayed correctly. I know how I get the rowcount and columncount, but I don't know how to find the value for the checkbox. I use an JavaScript-function to get these values. In the (Google Chrome)debugger I can't find the value for a checked box.
My table looks like this:

```
<tr>
  <th style="border:2px solid grey">selected</th>
  <th style="border:2px solid grey">id</th>
  <th style="border:2px solid grey">name</th>
</tr>
```

And inside my function I use these to get the rowcount and an array of items.

```
var length = document.getElementById(tableId).rows.length;
var container = document.getElementById(tableId).rows;
```

As you can see, the first column is where the checkedbox is. Also every checkbox has an id, like this:

```
<td id="checkbox0">false</td>
```

How can I access the value "false" (in this case)? I tried to access this value via `document.getElementById("checkbox0").checked` and if I set a variable for the table, like:

```
var container = document.getElementById(tableId);//html table
container[2].children[0];//table row 2, column 0
```

I do get a lot of attributes, but nothing I could clearly see as selected or not.

Comment: As from example, you don't have *real* checkboxes (`<input type="checkbox" />`). You can try something like this `if(container.rows[2].cells[0].innerHTML.trim() == 'false'){...}`

Comment: This method sadly only delivers (without the trim()) this: `<input type="checkbox">`, but not the value

Answer (score 0):

How about `document.getElementById("checkbox0").innerHTML` ? This is only to get the innerHTML between your tag `td`. I am quite confused because of you're asking of checkbox value, but I don't see any `input type="checkbox"` (or something similar)

(It should be in the comment. However since I cannot post a comment, I think I only have a choice to put here)

Comment: Because it is no real checkbox, it looks like it and behaves like it, thanks to EditableGrid.  And this returns `"<input type="checkbox">"`, if I do the innerHTML. What kind of variable it is, is defined by EditableGrid. It looks like this (window.onload): `editableGrid.load({
                metadata: [
                    { name: "id", datatype: "boolean", editable: true },
                    { name: "sensorid", datatype: "string", editable: false },
                    { name: "sensorname", datatype: "string", editable: false }
                ]
            });` (sorry for format)

Comment: I do not know much about EditableGrid, but I think you can try: `document.getElementById("checkbox0").getElementsByTagName("input").checked`

Answer (score 0):

You can get the status of the checkbox by:

```
$('#checkbox0').is(":checked");
```

Which returns true or false.

To select all selected checkbox you can check

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]:checked')
```

hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Well I feel dumb and I should feel dumb. The answer was pretty simple...to initialize a table (with editablegrid), I created a global JavaScript-object. I only had to do this in my code:

```
var value = editableGrid.getCell(row, column).firstChild.checked;
```

It's unclear, why the devs chose to do it like this, but that's how I get my correct values. Still thanks a lot everyone to take your time reading and trying to solve it.